# Minimum in a Tree

Tags: java, tree, minimum

I have to Find the minimum number in a Tree. I wrote this but it is not working. What do I have to change to run properly ? I know it doesn't take every value in the tree. But I don't know what to change to work.

```
public class MinTree {

    static Tree tree = new Tree( 24, 
                 new Tree( 45, 
                     null , 
                     new Tree(8, null , null) ) , 
                 new Tree ( 17, 
                     new Tree (74 , null , null ) , 
                     null ) );

    public int findMin(Tree tree){
        int min = 99999;
        Tree left, right;
        if(min > tree.getVal())
            min = tree.getVal();
        System.out.println(min + " ");
        if(tree.left() != null)
            return findMin(tree.left());
        if(tree.right() != null)
            return findMin(tree.right());


        return min;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MinTree mt = new MinTree();
        System.out.println("Minimum is :" + mt.findMin(tree));
        }
}
```

Tree class:

```
class Tree {

   public int obj;
   private int val;
   private Tree left, right;

   public Tree(int val, Tree left, Tree right){
     this.val = val;
     this.left = left;
     this.right = right;
   }

   public int getVal(){
      return val;
   }

   public Tree left(){
      return left;
   }

   public Tree right(){
      return right;
   }
}
```

Comment: What happens if the result in the right subtree is lower than the result from the left subtree? And what happens if the current value is lower than both of them?

Comment: You need to compare `tree.getVal()` to the minimum from the left and right trees, if they are non-null, and return the smallest of those (up to) three values. You are currently just returning the value from the left tree if it is non-null, or the right if that is non-null, and the current node's value otherwise.

Comment: Well I know how to do the minimum on every side, but I don't know how to make them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, it will only return the minimum value of the *leftiest* tree.

See, in the function `findMin(Tree tree)` you are stating that it has to return the value of `findMin(tree.left())`, because you are not comparing this value to `min`, just returning it.

Whenever a function finds a return code, it will return that value and finish the function. So, what you should so is:

```
if(tree.left() != null){
  int j = findMin(tree.left());
  if (j<min){
      min = j;
  }
}
```

And the same for tree.right. This way, it will take only the minimum value of the tree.

Also, why are you declaring two trees that are not being used? I mean `Tree left, right`, it doesn't do anything nor are none of them being used.

Also, at `System.out.println("Minimum is :" + mt.findMin(tree));` it could be that the system doesn't recognize the global variable tree.

Comment: I tried different things and I didn't delete the useless code :D . Thanks for the help.